# Microsoft Graph API redirect_uri doesn't allow query strings

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We're trying to move from the older WindowsLive API to the new Microsoft Graph API. In the process, we're running into difficulty with the required OAuth 2.0 `redirect_uri` parameter in the app.

According to the [Oauth 2.0 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2), the `redirect_uri` must be an absolute path but *can* contain a properly encoded query string.

In our Windows app, we've setup the absolute path - their application tool doesn't allow query strings to be added: `https://example.com/index.php`

The OAuth request we make uses a `redirect_uri` with URL Encoding, including query params. This is necessary, we use a CMS (Joomla) that needs to know what should handle the request:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
 response_type=code&
 client_id={string}&    
 redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Findex.php%3Foption%3Dcom_jfbconnect%26task%3Dauthenticate.callback%26provider%3Dwindowslive&
 scope=user.read&
 state={string}&
 access_type=offline&
 approval_prompt=auto
```

However, the Graph API rejects this with:

> "The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application"

Anyone else run into this or understand why the Graph API doesn't accept query parameters either in the app configuration or on the token requests?

Edit - 5/8 -  However, the application setup area does *not* allow query strings in the redirect_uri setting, which is correct according to the RFC. However, the Graph API isn't respecting this note of the RFC:

`The endpoint URI MAY include an "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" formatted (per Appendix B) query component ([RFC3986] Section 3.4), which MUST be retained when adding additional query parameters.`

Answer (score 3):

This isn't actually being rejected by Microsoft Graph. Microsoft Graph is simply an API and it doesn't generate or manage access tokens. That process is handled by Azure Active Directory.

The error you're getting is due to your `redirect_uri` not being configured in your app registration at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. The URL must explicitly match the URL configured in the registration. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code):

> The `redirect_uri` of your app, where authentication responses can be sent and received by your app. It must **exactly match** one of the redirect URIs you registered in the portal, except it must be url encoded.

For scenarios where you need to pass data through, you should encode those values in your `state` parameter. This will be returned to your redirect URI along with the authorization code.

Also note that neither `access_type=offline` or `approval_prompt=auto` are valid query parameters:

- To retrieve a `refresh_token`, you add `offline` to your list of scopes (`user.read+offline`).
- To set the type of prompt the user receives you use the `prompt` parameter. Valid options are `login`, `none`, and `consent`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree that the links don't match what's in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. However, the application setup area does *not* allow query strings in the redirect_uri setting, which is correct according to the RFC. However, the Graph API isn't respecting this note of the RFC:

`The endpoint URI MAY include an "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" formatted (per Appendix B) query component ([RFC3986] Section 3.4), which MUST be retained when adding additional query parameters.`

![App Setup area rejecting query strings](https://imgur.com/a/4erTKYu)

Comment: Sorry that comment is hideously formatted. I edited the original post with the same details for easier reading. Can't edit my comment anymore, but the image link above hopefully helps explain why I can't get the client side URL to match the server side one.

Comment: This is always the trouble with standards. How you interpret "MAY include" depends on your perspective. In this case, AAD considers them optional to the spec and hasn't implemented this aspect. I  would include this information in your `state`. When the user is redirected back, your endpoint can then decode the `state` value.

Comment: That's not a correct interpretation though. The 'MAY' is from the client side, the 'MUST' is for the server-side, which is AAD. So as a client, we should be able to include a query string and, if we do, it must be retained. This seems like a bug if there's no way to use query strings. The state parameter isn't an option either.. it's a CMS and if the CMS doesn't know to notify our code of a response, then we won't ever be able to act on it.

Comment: All other social networks (Google, Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Meetup, Github and more) all support a query string in some form.. either in their app settings for valid redirect URLs or by strictly following the RFC of only allowing an absolute path in the app settings but retaining the query string. Even the previous WindowsLive OAuth2 protocol supported this properly, which is what we are attempting to migrate from :/

Comment: That may be true but I can only help with what _is_ supported. Since neither of controls AAD, debating their interpretation of the standard isn't going to help much.

Comment: I understand, and appreciate your help. Do you know of any way to submit a bug report to Microsoft? I can see where I can give suggestions or ideas, but no way to report an issue.

Comment: I would add this to the [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory). I don't believe this would technically be considered a "bug" since this was clearly by design (i.e. someone wrote a very specific error message that you came across).

Comment: Azure support responded to me on Twitter and redirected me to the right MSDN area to post to. Will respond back here when I get more clarification from them. Thanks again!